# Prove that the matrix $N$ is similar over $\mathbb{R}$ to a matrix $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I would like to show that the matrix $N = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ \frac{-a^2}{b} & -a \end{bmatrix}$ is similar to $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Then I know that I need to find a matrix $P$ such that $N = P^{-1}AP.$ How can I find this matrix $P$ without relying on trial and error?

I am currently learning about characteristic value and characteristic polynomial in linear algebra.

Comment: $A$ is not diagonal.

Comment: What are the eigenvalues of $N$? (In fact, it only has a single eigenvalue, of algebraic multiplicity $2$.) Can you find an eigenvector of that eigenvalue?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. From the title it seems you want to know whether $A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix, but from the question you are asking about $N$ being similar to $A$, which is not diagonal.

Comment: It is also not similar to a diagonal matrix, since it is nilpotent and the only matrix that is both nilpotent and diagonalizable is the zero matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Similarity is about a change of basis. You're looking for a basis $v_1, v_2$ such that $N v_1 = v_2$ and $Nv_2 = 0$, because that's how $A$ acts on the standard basis. Start with $v_2$. By row reduction (or just observation), you should be able to get $v_2 = \left[\begin{array}{c} b \\ -a \end{array}\right]$. Then, again by row reduction or observation, you can find $v_1 = \left[\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \end{array}\right]$. (Note that these solutions are not unique, but they are one example that works. You could change them by a constant multiple.)

So now we want $P$ to be a matrix taking $v_1$ to $\left[\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right]$ and $v_2$ to $\left[\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \end{array}\right]$, and $P^{-1}$ to do the reverse. 
$$P^{-1} = \left[\begin{array}{cc} v_1 & v_2 \end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & b \\ 1 & -a \end{array}\right], \quad P = \left[\begin{array}{cc} -a & -b \\ -1 & 0 \end{array}\right]$$